# Dispatch action in useEffect when component mounts

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I wrote a custom hook to dispatch an API fetch using Redux and Redux thunk. The action works fine and my hook works fine if I add an `if` to check if my state has the data in it:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';
import { shallowEqual, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

import { getOrderInfo } from '../actions/ordersActions';

function useCheckOrderReduxState() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { orderInfo } = useSelector((state) => state.order, shallowEqual);

    const boundAction = useCallback(() => {
        return dispatch(getOrderInfo(id));
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!orderInfo) {
            boundAction();
        }
    }, [boundAction, orderInfo]);
}

export default useCheckOrderReduxState;
```

My problem is that I want to dispatch the `getOrderInfo` only once when I render the page which has the hook, every time this page is rendered, even if I already have data inside `orderInfo`.

If I remove the `if (!orderInfo)` from the `useEffect`, I enter in an infinite loop, because the component is rerendered every time the state updates, and if I keep this `if`, my hook won't dispatch the action if there's already data in `orderInfo`.

I need the state to update every time I render the component, because it can have an outdated state, and I want to fetch the latest state from the API.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!